Avoid a sub query to get a maximum number
I wrote the below query which I am trying to get the maximum transaction number of a code and status, is there a way I can re-write avoiding the sub-select?
SELECT CUST_NAME, TRANSCANTIONS_NB
FROM TRANSCANTIONS 
WHERE CODE = '477' 
AND STATUS IN ( '1' , '7' ) 
AND TRANSCANTIONS_NB = ( 
    SELECT MAX(TRANSCANTIONS_NB)
    FROM TRANSCANTIONS
    WHERE CODE ='477' AND STATUS IN ( '1' , '7' ) 
)

I am looking for a better performing solution which works in both Oracle and SQL Server.

Please provide a [MRE] with sample data and desired results.

Is TRANSCANTIONS_NB numeric? If so, select top 1 ... order by TRANSCANTIONS_NB desc`

@DaleK its numeric , I have add t-sql because i am using sql server and oracle.

See my comment below the answer, T-SQL is not Oracle... its only SQL Server.\

Why do you want to avoid the sub-query? If it works...

@DaleK I though t-sql is universal for all the database like sql. thanks for correcting my information, I am trying to avoid it for performance issue. this table contains hundreds of millions, I removed the status in this query and I specified one value , still checking if the sub query can be removed

Why do you assume that a sub-query will perform badly? With the correct indexes it shouldn't matter how many rows you have. In fact it might perform better than the answer you accepted. You should always include you actual goal (i.e. performance) when asking a question, that way you'll get an answer that addresses your real issue.

You also need to include what versions of RDBMS you are using, because all RDBMS introduce new features all the time.

You could use a TOP query here:
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES CUST_NAME, TRANSACTIONS_NB
FROM TRANSCANTIONS
WHERE CODE = '477' AND STATUS IN ('1', '7')
ORDER BY TRANSCANTIONS_NB DESC;

Using TOP 1 WITH TIES rather than just TOP 1 will ensure that multiple records will be returned in case there are more than one record having the max TRANSCANTIONS_NB value.
While Oracle does support WITH TIES in its FETCH FIRST clause, this is only available from 12+, and on top of that, we have to specify a number of tied records to retrieve.  Therefore, on Oracle, a more canonical way to do this would use RANK() (or even ROW_NUMBER()), which also means we need a subquery:
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT CUST_NAME, TRANSACTIONS_NB,
           RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TRANSCANTIONS_NB DESC) rnk
    FROM TRANSCANTIONS
    WHERE CODE = '477' AND STATUS IN ('1', '7')
)

SELECT CUST_NAME, TRANSACTIONS_NB
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;


I added t-sql because I need to use it in sql server and oracle , for oracle they dont have top 1 with ties. how to do that also in oracle ?

@Baalback T-SQL is not Oracle... its only SQL Server and some of the related family. You need to tag both SQL Server and Oracle

@DaleK ... or better yet, just ask for one database at a time, and save the other database for a different question.  Most folks who will read this Q&A in the future won't be searching for SQL Server and Oracle concurrently.

@TimBiegeleisen if the OP is looking for a solution that works for multiple databases, that is one of the few occasions they should tag multiple (or none lol but ensure they write it in the question).

If you want to have only one row with the maximum of transactions, you can use this query that does not have any subquery :
SELECT CUST_NAME, TRANSCANTIONS_NB, 
       MAX(TRANSCANTIONS_NB) OVER(PARTITION BY CUST_NAME, TRANSCANTIONS_NB) AS NB
FROM   TRANSCANTIONS 
WHERE  CODE = '477' 
       AND STATUS IN ( '1' , '7' ) 
ORDER  BY NB DESC OFFSET 0 ROW FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY;

But there is two flaws :

the number of rows returned by the original query can be 1 or more depending on the fact that many rows can have the max TRANSCANTIONS_NB value.

I am not sure that this query will be more efficient... You need to try and examine the query execution plan.


Last, you can create indexes to have better performances.
For SQL Server:
CREATE INDEX _X001 ON TRANSCANTIONS (CODE, STATUS, TRANSCANTIONS_NB) INCLUDE (CUST_NAME);

For Oracle:
CREATE INDEX _X001 ON TRANSCANTIONS (CODE, STATUS, TRANSCANTIONS_NB, CUST_NAME);

